# Can requireJs can replace sprockets in a rails 3.x - backbone app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, backbone.js, requirejs, sprockets

In the context of a rails 3.2 rails with a backbone client side app I try to figure out how to organize the javascript files. 
It is not clear if requireJs could replace or be used instead of sprockets.
Reading this page on requireJs http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-optimization.html#usagemake me think that sprockets can be replace.
Sprockets seems to be used as a rails tool in the assets pipeline feature.

To confirm my thought,I've seen this recent gem on github https://github.com/jwhitley/requirejs-rails. it proposed to replace sprockets by requireJS. Seems a good starting point. Is there any altenative?

could sprockets and requireJs live happy together? - is there any advantage with this solution?